# Why does iOS delay when saving Core Data via a UIManagedDocument?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm using Core Data to persist some information in a SQLite database. I'm testing with the simulator, and using `sqlite3` to query the database and verify that I'm storing what I expect.

What I'm seeing is that the data doesn't appear in the SQLite database until a good 15-20 seconds after I've saved it.

Here's the code that I've cut my save down to:

```
NSEntityDescription *customerType = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CustomerType" inManagedObjectContext:context];
CustomerType *ct = [[CustomerType alloc]initWithEntity:customerType insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context ];
ct.code = code;

NSError* error = nil;
if (![context save:&error] || error)
    NSLog(@"Saved new customer (error=%@)", [error debugDescription]);
```

The save operation completes without error.

Any hints as to why I'm seeing this delay? Is my save operation not running properly, or is the delay in persisting the data an artifact of the simulator?

Comment: In the future, please be sure to tag your questions as `Objective-C` if they have anything to do with objc development, as it tells StackOverflow how to highlight the code that is posted.

Comment: @Andrew: please create an answer from your solution and then accept it.  At the moment it looks like the question is unanswered which will make it harder for people with the same problem as you to search for the answer.

Comment: Sorry — bit rusty. Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution!

I create the `NSManagedObjectContext` via a `UIManagedDocument`. To persist the data in a timely manner I need to save the managed document, not just save the changes I've made to the object graph in the managed object context.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I've been trying to solve this problem for two days!

Answer (score 5):

Because you should use:

```
    [self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL
            forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting
           completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {                   
               if (success) {                       
                   NSLog(@"saved");
               } else {                       
                   NSLog(@"unable to save");
               }
               }];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIManagedDocument` has nested parent/child context architecture. The delay is caused by not saving parent context manually. What you did is only commit changes from child context to parent context, not from parent context to persistent store. The parent context's auto saving is called by runtime every now and then, hence the delay.

The fix is simple: either save the document by `saveToURL` like Flink suggested, or save **BOTH** child context and parent context. The former approach is simpler and works in most situation. If you want to use the second approach, be careful to reference each context correctly. `document.managedObjectContext` will get you the CHILD context (on main thread), `document.managedObjectContext.parentContext` will get you the parent context.

Comment: What circumstances does the second approach have an advantage?

Comment: I think it depends on what parent context is used for in your app. For example, you can download photo on the private thread that creates the parent context, corresponding to some object property (like photo's owner) saved from child context. Do modification to the managed object according to the payload, then save the parent context.