# Fixing delay in Core Data Storage

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7

So I am building in a hide function into my application. In my settings menu I have a `UISwitch` that should allow the user to hide themselves. I have created the `UISwitch`'s IBAction like so:

```
-(IBAction)hideUserToggle:(id)sender {

    AppDelegate *newAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [newAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newOwner;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LoggedInUser" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    newOwner = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"LoggedInUser" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    if (_hideUser.on) {

        if ([objects count] == 0) {

            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
        } else {

            matches = objects[0];
            [newOwner setValue:@"userHidden" forKeyPath:@"isHidden"];
            NSLog(@"%@",[matches valueForKeyPath:@"isHidden"]);
        }
    } else {

        if([objects count] == 0) {

            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
        } else {

            matches = objects[0];
            [newOwner setValue:@"userNotHidden" forKeyPath:@"isHidden"];
            NSLog(@"%@",[matches valueForKeyPath:@"isHidden"]);
        }
    }
}
```

This should set the value of the Core Data String that I use to determine whether a person is hidden or not, which I use later in my code as a conditional for loading data. However when I test this feature it doesn't seem to update the persistent data store (Core Data) when the user has flipped the switch. I have looked around everywhere and I found a reference to there being a delay in updating Core Data here -> [Why does IOS delay when saving core data via a UIManagedDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789697/why-does-ios-delay-when-saving-core-data-via-a-uimanageddocument), however it doesn't seem to provide the answer to my problem.

I want to be able flip the switch and save that value so that when the user swipes over to another view controller it is immediately aware that the user has gone into "hiding" or offline so it does not show certain information.

Answer (score 0):

A `NSManagedObjectContext` is a scratchpad. Changes you make within the context exist only within the context unless or until you save them to the context's parent (either the persistent store itself or another context).

You're not saving them. I'd assume you're therefore not seeing the change elsewhere because you're using different contexts. Meanwhile the change eventually migrates because somebody else happens to save.

See [`-save:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:) for details on saving.

(aside: the key-value coding `[newOwner setValue:@"userHidden" forKeyPath:@"isHidden"]`-style mechanism is both uglier and less efficient than using an editor-generated managed object subclass; hopefully it's just there while you're debugging?)

Comment: I added a [context save:&error] however it doesn't seem to change the functionality.

Comment: Are you confident you haven't a thread confinement or context lifecycle error elsewhere? Managed objects, if taken off their native queue/thread or if living beyond their context can appear to function correctly except that they're no longer connected to the store (technically you're in the realm of undefined behaviour but that often appears empirically to be what occurs; though raising an exception is just as likely)